# Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above

Tags: android

I am using an Eclipse Kepler.

In **Windows->preferences->Android:** I am getting the following Error

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or
>   above.  Current version is 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206.
>   Please update ADT to the latest version.

My sdk version exactly set to these directory `D:\android\sdk`.There was no problem in that.

Comment: Update your ADT with 23.0 and try....

Comment: @MD for that I have to download new ADT Bundle `http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html`.Without these I can't resolve these problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I solved these problem by deleting the Adt Bundle Which was shown
  error.
- Then *Extract* the new adt bundle to solve these problem.After that just updated the Android 4.4.2(API 19) in Android Sdk Manager.
- you are getting these `error` because of updating the `Android Sdk
  Tools 22.6.2`.Below I shown the  Screenshot of it.

  [image]
- Install everything as shown in the screenshot itself.Then these
  problem will not occur again.

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse:
1. Go to Help
2. Click check for updates.

If you are using Eclipse kepler then ADT update 23.0 is currently unavailable for it.
There is some glitch with it.

Comment: @Shink no you're wrong. I am working with Eclipse Kelper with 23.0 ADT.

Comment: @MD I have been trying to update my ADT to 23.0 for so many days and I don't see any updates for it in my eclipse.

Comment: @MD today morning itself I am also not getting any problem while using the eclipse kelper with 23.0.But Later I am getting these problem.

Comment: @MD as Shink said there was no updates in his eclipse. same thing happened to me.

Comment: @MD I restarted it several times.but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Shink I do not understand why you guys not able to update... because i have successfully updated my ADT and Eclipse only in first try.....also check your internet connection and speed...it is more important over here..

Comment: @Shink no.now I am trying to download a new sdk tools only form here `http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem few days ago and I had to reinstall ADT, here you can download the last stable version:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem after updating eclipse. Download New SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html